# request for index path for global index 1793701674059 when there are only 6 items in the collection view

Tags: ios, crash, uicollectionview, performbatchupdates

UICollectionView crash when performBatchUpdates after reload data.I don't perform any delete or add operation,only refresh data after net request success.
code like this

```
- (void)reloadData:(NSArray *)dataArray {
self.dataSourceArray = dataArray;
[_collectionView reloadData];
[_collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if ([_collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0] > 0) {
        [_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
    }
}];
```

}

function reloadData maybe call twice consecutive and fast,everytime use new data reload collection view.
i think somewhere use incorrect with collection view,but i can't find it.

Comment: What is the exception message and what line of code does it crash on?

Comment: Title is the specific exception message and crash on the last line,that is the block's bracket ;

Comment: Please add the crash log as it helps to figure out the problem. Additionally you don't need to call batch updates to simply scroll and/or reload data. It is suggested when only insertion or deletion takes place on individual rows.

Comment: @Rikh Thanks. I also feel unnecessary call batch updates.But when perform scroll immediately after reload data, frequently can't scroll to the right item,so i use batch updates to fix that.